# How to copy a list of files and adjust destination filenames on the fly?

Tags: find, cp, xargs, file-copy, cpio

When I don't need to adjust destination filenames I can do something like this:

```
$ find -type f -name '*.pat' -print0  | xargs -O cp -t /path/to/dest
```

It is safe because the filenames may even contain newline characters.

An alternative:

```
$ find -type f -name '*.pat' -print0 | cpio -p -0 -d /path/to/dest
```

Now I have the problem that the destination is a VFAT filesystem ... thus certain characters are just not allowed in filenames (e.g. '?'). That means that I have to adjust the destination filenames.

Something like

```
for i `find -type f -name '*.pat'` ; do
    cp "$i" `echo $i | sed 's/?/_/'`
done
```

works only for filenames without spaces - I could change IFS to just newline - but how to set '\0' as IFS?

And still - the for loop leads to as much forks/execs (of mv/sed) as you have files - which is much more excessive than the few forks/execs needed for the two examples in the beginning.

What are the alternatives to solve that problem?

Comment: To get rid of the one process per file limit you'd have to use a special batch copy/rename application, but I wouldn't worry about spawning too many processes - the real bottleneck is very likely to be somewhere else.

Comment: @peterph, bottleneck probably not - just perhaps  a waste of resources - depending on number of files of course. Besides that - such loop-less shell constructs tend to be more concise. Cf. my answer involving GNU tar and a loop based approach.

Comment: Could be waste of resources if you did **just** that and nothing else. Concise... well, yes, but at an expense - '?' is not the only character forbidden on *FAT so you can easily get rename conflicts, which you can't really resolve smoothly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `pax` as found on Debian, Suse, OpenBSD, NetBSD at least:

```
find . -type f -name '*.pat' -print0 | pax -0rws'/?/_/gp' /path/to/dest/
```

`pax` is a [standard utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pax.html) (contrary to `tar` or `cpio`), but its `-0` option is not, though can be found in a few implementations.

If there's both a `?.pat` and `_.pat` files, they will end up replaced with same name so one will overwrite the other in the destination. Same, if there's a `_` and `?` directory, their content will be merged inside the `_` directory in the destination.

With GNU `sort` and GNU `uniq`, you can check for conflicts beforehand with:

```
find . -type f -name '*.pat' -print0 |
  tr '?' _ |
  sort -z |
  uniq -zd |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

Which would report conflicting files (but not directories).

You could use `zsh`'s `zmv` which would take care of conflicts, but that would still mean one `mkdir` and one `cp` per file:

```
autoload zmv
mkdir-and-cp() {mkdir -p -- $3:h && cp $@}
zmv -n -Qp mkdir-and-cp '(**/)*.pat(D.)' '/path/to/dest/$f:gs/?/_/'
```

(remove `-n` when happy).

Answer (score 3):

One can use GNU tar for it:

```
$ find -type f -name '*.pat' -print0  | tar -c -f - --null --files-from - \
    | tar -C /path/to/dest -v -x -f - --show-transformed --transform 's/?/_/g'
```

Advantages:

- only 3 forks/execs needed (independent of the number of files)
- the selection of source files is very flexible - you can use the full power of (GNU) find for that (i.e. when you need to be more specific than a simple shell globbing like `bash` or `ksh93`'s `**` allows)
- it is also safe for filenames containing newlines
- the transform part is very flexible, too - for example you can use something like `s/[^A-Za-z0-9 _-]/_/g` which replaces all characters not in the character class `[A-Za-z0-9 _-]`

Comment: +1 Nice solution, but handling of possible filename conflicts is next to none. However without a special utility (counting those written in e.g Python), I'm afraid there is no better option than a shell loop with checking.

Comment: @peterph, you could add `--keep-old-files` to the 2nd (GNU) tar command ;)

Comment: Sure, but you usually want some kind of error message printed or even an automagic rename to happen in these caases.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to approach this is to define the *allowed* characters and bypass transposition for them instead of seeking to define characters *to* transpose. It is more complex than just defining a limited character set which is acceptable, because there are certain rules about what is allowed *where* in a filename. As such, this uses a limited subset that should be safe (as far as I can tell from reading FAT32 docs). Something like this should work (bash4+):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar nullglob

for file in **/*.pat; do
    echo cp -t "${1:-.}" "${file//[![:alnum:].\-_\/]/_}"
done
```

This will return something like this:

```
$ > bar\?.pat
$ > baz\*.pat
$ > foo.pat
$ ./script foo
cp -t baz*.pat foo/baz_.pat
cp -t bar?.pat foo/bar_.pat
cp -t foo.pat foo/foo.pat
```

Pass the dir to copy to as the first argument. Remove the call to `echo` if you want go ahead and do what it outputs.

Comment: Ok, IFS issue is dealt with via a `**/*.pat` globbing. But because of the main loop I still get one fork/exec for each file. On the one hand the recode() function eliminates an extra sed call - but on the other hand its kind of verbose - I mean too verbose for using it interactively on the command line prompt.

Comment: Beware that `bash` recursive globbing follows symlinks.

Comment: Note that the syntax is `cp -t dest-dir files`. You'd need to create the directories, remove `-t` and add `--`. Also, you can replace your `recode` with `${file//[!...]/_}`.